# HTML attribute to return true based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat with input box in each repeated item. I have set the autofocus to input.

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

So autofocus will be applied to all items. However, there's a bug in iOS where the last input box is auto focused instead of the first one.

I need to set it to return true based on the condition as in:

```
<input autofocus="{{$first  ? 'true' : 'false' }}" >
```

Any idea how to accomplish this with Angular?

Comment: `$first  ? 'true' : 'false'` can just be shortened to `$first`; don't use the string representations of `'true'` and `'false'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom **directive** to focus an element

Directive

```
app.directive('autofocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function(scope, element,attrs) {
       $timeout(function() {
       if(attrs.autofocus==='true'){
        element[0].focus();
       }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['first','second','third','fourth','fifth'];
});
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" autofocus="{{$index==0}}" ng-model="name" />
    </div>
```

Demo plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/tw9tLzEyfILpEFIR3Tjh?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be valid. Try change the index number.